# univariate analysis using qplot function from ggplot2 package

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
X <- round(quantile(Retaildata$monthly_salary.x,c(.90,.92,.94,.96,.98,1)),0)
Y <- c('P90','P92','P94','P96','P98','P100')
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x=Y,y=X,label=X,geom = c('text','point'), hjust = -.25)
```

Why `P100` is shown on the leftmost side?
How do I take it to the last, i.e. to the right?

[image: qplot_graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
set.seed(1)
X <- round(quantile(abs(rnorm(1000))*12500,c(.90,.92,.94,.96,.98,1)),0)
Y <- c('P90','P92','P94','P96','P98','P100')

# 'mixedsort' orders character strings containing embedded numbers so that 
# the numbers are numerically sorted rather than sorted by character value 
library(gtools)
Y <- factor(Y, levels=mixedsort(Y))

library(ggplot2)
qplot(x=Y,y=X,label=X,geom = c('text','point'), hjust = -.25)
```

[image]